# Unhide the keyboard in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

In my application what is want is when user clicks on button next view is pushed and default keyboard should be open in the pushed view .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a text field or something in that view you need to do this:

`[myTextView becomeFirstResponder]` in your `viewDidLoad` method.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to use -becomeFirstResponder: in the -viewDidAppear: method.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];        
    [yourTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

This will make the keyboard appear.

Comment: ya thanks it worked one more thing can i  change color of keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

in your next view, call the becomeFirstResponder method from the input field.

e.g. [[nextViewController] usernameField] becomeFirstResponder];